# cannot open source file "iostream". Please run the 'Select IntelliSense Configuration...' command to locate your system headers

Tags: visual-c++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsEHl.png)

i have download the Visual studio on my mac M2 silicon and there is problem in #include , i have download the extinction in Visual Studio like Code Runner and don’t solve the problem and all i see in this case not in M silicon processor

Comment: It's more helpful if we see actual code, not images of code.  (Among other things, it lets us see if you have some funky unicode causing issues.)